# When all products are displayed - color swatch does not work

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a custom block where I display all the products. I need to add a selection of product options by color, size, etc. on each card. I took the code from product-variant-options.liquid and product-variant-picker.liquid to the product page and inserted it into a card that I display in the list.

Now the problem is that when I click on some options, they do not switch and there is an error in the console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'). Error in global.js file:

```
updateOptions() {
    const fieldsets = Array.from(this.querySelectorAll('fieldset'));
    this.options = fieldsets.map((fieldset) => {
      return Array.from(fieldset.querySelectorAll('input')).find((radio) => radio.checked).value;
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to add option pickers to a product list page where each one has a picker?
My code:

```js
//product-variant-picker

{%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <variant-radios
    id="variant-radios-{{ section.id }}"
    class="no-js-hidden"
    data-section="{{ section.id }}"
    data-url="{{ product.url }}"
    {% if update_url == false %}
      data-update-url="false"
    {% endif %}
  >
    {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
      <fieldset class="js product-form__input">
        {% render 'custom-product-variant-options', product: product, option: option %}
      </fieldset>
    {%- endfor -%}
    <script type="application/json">
      {{ product.variants | json }}
    </script>
  </variant-radios>
{%- endunless -%}

//product-variant-options



{%- liquid
  assign variants_available_arr = product.variants | map: 'available'
  assign variants_option1_arr = product.variants | map: 'option1'
  assign variants_option2_arr = product.variants | map: 'option2'
  assign variants_option3_arr = product.variants | map: 'option3'

  assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id
-%}

{%- for value in option.values -%}
  {%- liquid
    assign option_disabled = true

    for option1_name in variants_option1_arr
      case option.position
        when 1
          if variants_option1_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 2
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
        when 3
          if option1_name == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option1 and variants_option2_arr[forloop.index0] == product.selected_or_first_available_variant.option2 and variants_option3_arr[forloop.index0] == value and variants_available_arr[forloop.index0]
            assign option_disabled = false
          endif
      endcase
    endfor
  -%}

  {% liquid
    assign variant_needed = null 
    for variant in product.variants 
      if variant.options contains value 
        assign variant_needed = variant 
      endif 
    endfor 
  %}

  <input
    type="radio"
    id="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    name="{{ option.name }}"
    value="{{ value | escape }}"
    form="{{ product_form_id }}"
    {% if option.selected_value == value %}
      checked
    {% endif %}
    {% if option_disabled %}
      class="disabled"
    {% endif %}
  >

  {% if option.name == 'Color' %}
    <label
      class="color-swatch"
      style="background-color: {{ variant_needed.metafields.custom.color }}"
      for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
    >
    </label>
  {% else %}
    <label for="{{ section.id }}-{{ option.position }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
      {{ value }}
    </label>
  {% endif %}
{%- endfor -%}

//product list

{%- assign product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id -%}
  <ul
        class="products-with-filter__content-products  grid product-grid grid--3-col-desktop"
        data-id="{{ section.id }}"
      >
        {%- paginate collections.all.products by section.settings.products_per_page -%}
          {% for product in collections.all.products %}
         <li>
...

 <div class="variants-picker__list">
        {% render 'custom-product-variant-picker', product: product, product_form_id: product_form_id %}
      </div>
</li>
        {%- endpaginate -%}
      </ul>
```